# How to specify an initial size using C++ 11 style non-default-constructible allocator?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, allocator

In a prior thread about an update to Visual Studio 2015 `std::list::sort` handling a list with no default allocators, this was one of the examples used to create such a list, based on a Microsoft example for no default allocator.

I'm trying to figure out how to create an instance of a `std::list` with an initial (non-zero) size, without having to do a resize after creating an empty list.

```
// this part of the code based on Microsoft example
template <class T>  
struct Mallocator  
{  
    typedef T value_type;  
    Mallocator(T) noexcept {} //default ctor not required by STL  

    // A converting copy constructor:  
    template<class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) noexcept {}  
    template<class U> bool operator==(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept  
    {  
        return true;  
    }  
    template<class U> bool operator!=(const Mallocator<U>&) const noexcept  
    {  
        return false;  
    }  
    T* allocate(const size_t n) const;  
    void deallocate(T* const p, size_t) const noexcept;  
};  

template <class T>  
T* Mallocator<T>::allocate(const size_t n) const  
{
    if (n == 0)  
    {  
        return nullptr;  
    }  
    if (n > static_cast<size_t>(-1) / sizeof(T))  
    {  
        throw std::bad_array_new_length();  
    }  
    void* const pv = malloc(n * sizeof(T));  
    if (!pv) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }  
    return static_cast<T*>(pv);  
}  

template<class T>  
void Mallocator<T>::deallocate(T * const p, size_t) const noexcept  
{  
    free(p);  
}  

typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

#define COUNT (4*1024*1024-1)   // number of values to sort

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    // this line from a prior answer
    // the (0) is needed to prevent compiler error, but changing the
    // (0) to (COUNT) or other non-zero value has no effect, the size == 0
    std::list <uint64_t, Mallocator<uint64_t>> ll(Mallocator<uint64_t>(0));
    // trying to avoid having to resize the list to get an initial size.
    ll.resize(COUNT, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried some more variations on this which triggered Visual Studio to show various combinations of parameters, and variation 12 of 12 showed the parameters in the correct order: (count, value, allocator). Note in the case of VS 2015, there is no option for (count, allocator), the value needs to be included. The value in the last parameter, <uint64_t>(0), doesn't matter, it just needs to be the proper type.

```
    std::list <uint64_t, Mallocator<uint64_t>> ll(COUNT, 0, Mallocator<uint64_t>(0));
```

Comment: What is surprising is that constructor with parameters (count, allocator) [appears in standard C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list) on one hand; on the other hand, VS2015 is said to be conformant with C++14 in its vast majority (except [some points](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019)). In VS2017, this is indeed implemented, variation 11 of 12.

Comment: @Bentoy13 - For VS2015, variation 11 of 12 is (count, value). I have a multi-boot system, XP, XP X64, both with VS2005 and VS2010, Win 7 with VS 2015, Win 10 with VS 2019. The change to std::list::sort() was made with VS2015, which is why I was focusing on that version. I updated my answer to note that it's VS2015 that doesn't have (count, allocator) as an option.

Comment: I am convinced by your tests yet it is surprising to find no mention about changes in STL container constructors in release notes. I think your post + answer are valuable.

Comment: @Bentoy13 - the change made to std::list::sort() in VS2015 wasn't mentioned either.  The other bit of confusion is the last parameter, it needs a value, but only to establish the type of the value, and the value itself doesn't matter, so I used <uint64_t>(0). Initially I was thinking this value would be a count, but it's just used to provide a type.

Comment: @Bentoy13 - with VS 2019, variation 14 of 15 is (count, allocator),  variation15 of 15 is (count, value, allocator).